# compile dependencies into a library itself

Tags: c++, dll, libraries

I want to provide a large library I programmed (further called "my lib") to another developer who is building a larger application (further called "target application"). My lib is under very experimental development and I may change dependencies, versions of those, etc. quite often. To call the developer of the target application every other week to change dependencies looks like an unclean option to me. It would be very nice, to just exchange a *single* (or a couple of) file(s) that include all of my dependencies, which brings me to my question:

Is it possible for me to compile all of my dependencies into the library I'm building in such a way that the developer of the target application will not have to include the header files, dlls libs, etc. of the dependencies of *my lib*?

Something similar is possible for executable files, where staticly linked libraries will be compiled into the executable.

Is something similar possible for this use-case? I say "library" on purpose because I dont care if it results in a DLL or staticly linked file.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer is this: use a proper dependency manager.

Ensure you have a proper build system setup where no matter the usage requirement change, no changes are required for projects down the line. Coupled with a dependency manager, it won't matter how your usage requirement are: the user will only update the library and the tools take care of the rest.

CMake exported targets are excellent for this kind of purpose. A proper package manager such as vcpkg can completely handle this with a custom repository.

---

Now for the boring and unoptimal answer.

What you could do is compile your library in a dynamic library. Only update the DLL and the headers and ask statically linked libraries will be updated too, since they are statically linked into the DLL.

However, when doing this, you expose yourself to some problems:

First, you'll most likely have to ship you libraries headers too, or even compile definition. This might change usage requirements of your library. To hide all of this, you may need to wrap all your classes in pimpl wrappers. This will prevent you from using many features, such as templates or constexpr.

Second, the moment you ship your library as a DLL, you expose yourself to ABI. Users *will* attempt to only update the DLL without recompiling, and any ABI compatibility issues will be brought up. Adding a virtual function, changing the name of a function, adding a member to a class, changing the meaning or the result of a function, even fixing a bug can result in an ABI break.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. When researching on this, I came across the pImpl idiom. wouldn't this solve the issue? I'd put an interface over my code, that only uses c code and  forward declare my implementation in the private sector of my interface class. So the user would not need to include my dependencies as its nowhere in the inferface header.

Comment: @Dennis yeah it would solve part of the whole problem, with a massive cost in term of design. Not being able to use C++ features or type in the interface is a very massive tradeoff for not using a package manager.

Comment: Okay, I'll have a look into it to see if I really need c++ features in the interface or what kind of package manager we could use. Would you mind adding the third option "using a pImpl idiom" to your answer so I can mark this question answered? Someone searching this question might want to see all three options,  and comments are not as "visible" as answers. (I cant edit your answer)

Comment: @Dennis I already mentionned pimpl in a paragraph in my answer I think